# What is the best way to integrate a react-native application into another react-native application?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, integration

I've implemented a react-native application and now I want to enhance it by adding along side it another different react-native application. 
What i want to achieve is to keep the two application separated in order to continue to implement them as two separate application, and avoid to rewrite them completely as a single application.

Both application are using react-redux to handle their states. The first brutal approach which I have tried is to wrap one of the two application into a npm package and add it as a dependence of the other one. Then I've just added a tab to the main application which when clicked navigate to the second application. This approach seems to work, but I don't think is the best way to do it.

Do you think there could be any sort of problem doing so? Is there a more intelligent and elegant way to do it? I know it is kinda a generic question, so I would accept also an article/link about this argument.

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure out the best way to approach this? I'm looking to do the same thing. I've tried packing one app and installing it via npm although I seem to be having alot of dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a git tag of your second application and can add it as a dependency in your first application.
2. You can also add it as a git sub-module.
   P.S. i prefer the first one.

Comment: Thank you. I think this might be a more elegant solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it would be **Linking** as described here: [Basic usage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html#basic-usage). So, you can easily pass needed parameters to the other app you want to open and also read them as app opens. Check this simple example:

**Caller app:**

```
Linking.openURL('calleeApp://app?param1=test&param2=test2')
```

**Callee app:**

```
componentDidMount() {
  Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
    if (url) {
      console.log('Initial url is: ' + url);
    }
  }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
}
```

do not forget to import it first:

```
import { Linking } from "react-native";
```

Let me know if it worked for you!

Comment: Great, but doing like so, the user needs to install both my application as two different application. Am I wrong? This is not what I want. I'm looking for a solution where both the application lives or seems to live inside the same application.